# OutboundMessageListener doesn't detect outgoing sms

Tags: blackberry, sms

The following piece of code should print out a message when an sms is sent from the device. I've tried it several times on the simulator but nothing gets printed when I send an sms. What am I doing wrong? Why doesn't the app pick up that an sms has been sent.

```
public class BackGroundApp extends UiApplication implements OutboundMessageListener, javax.wireless.messaging.MessageListener {

    private MessageConnection messageConnection;


    public static void main(String args[]) 
    {
        BackGroundApp theApp = new BackGroundApp();
        theApp.enterEventDispatcher();
    }

    public BackGroundApp(){
     try {
            MessageConnection _mc = (MessageConnection)Connector.open("sms://");
            _mc.setMessageListener(this);

         } catch (IOException e) {}

}

    public void notifyIncomingMessage(MessageConnection messageconnection){


    }

    public void notifyOutgoingMessage(javax.wireless.messaging.Message message) {

      System.out.println("SMS just sent from your device!");  

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

1. You need to register your listener with the MessageConnection per the [API documentation](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/7.0.0api/net/rim/blackberry/api/sms/OutboundMessageListener.html).
2. The simulator can't really send SMS messages so you may have to do this on a device.